# .Doing a super.requestRectangleOnScreen when i click on inputtext in popup

Tags: android, cordova-2.0.0, jquery-mobile-popup

I had created an input for phone in which when a user click on the input-text a popup window will open which has a for in put text to enter like country code,area code , local no and extension if available. Know the issue is when a user click on the input text in the popup window popup window starts moving up and down so when i check the console log it shows some thing like this:

```
08-20 15:55:50.546: E/webtextview(2500): ....Doing a super.requestRectangleOnScreen....
```

can any tell whats the reasons for this happens only on the phone its working fine on the emulator.

Comment: hi, even i get the same error, did you solve your issue? @Neerav Shah

Comment: no i didnt found any solution if you find one let me know. @DD.